# Correct Niqqud for ואטהר in Sefira Nusach

Tags: tefilla, pronunciation, sefirat-ha-omer, nuschaot

Context: In the Ashkenaz / Sefard (and possibly others) Nuschaos of Sefira, there is a prayer starting with the words "Ribbono Shel Olam [רבונו של עולם]" that is said. Towards the end of this prayer there is the phrase ואטהר ואתקדש בקדשה של מעלה...

What I'm confused about is the pronunciation of the word ואטהר. I have always pronounced the word (as it's printed in just about every Siddur I know) with a [Segol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segol) under the Aleph. However, someone recently told me that he pronounces the word as if there is a [Chiriq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiriq) under the aleph. To make sure, I asked him to double-check and he confirmed - it is printed this way in his Siddur.

So: Is there some source for this difference? Is it a printer error? Have you ever seen this difference? What's going on here?

Comment: I've noticed this for many years - you are not alone. Unfortunately,I have no answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote this question in to [Artscroll](http://www.artscroll.com), and finally got an answer. Here is the relevant snippet of the email I received (emphasis is theirs - not mine):

> 1. **וְאִטָּהֵר וְאֶתְקַדֵּשׁ  ‎— וְאִטָּהֵר**   with the Chirik under the aleph  is the way the words are vowelized in the original ArtScroll English translation Siddur and the original Pesach Machzor.
> 2. **וְאֶטָּהֵר וְאֶתְקַדֵּשׁ  —‎ וְאֶטָּהֵר** with the segol under the aleph is the way the words are vowelized in the Tefilas Shlomo, Yitzchak Yair, and Ner Naftali all-Hebrew Siddurim, as well as the Wasserman Siddur and the Interlinear Siddurim and Machzorim.
>
> **Neither version is wrong** and both appear in other Siddurim. The reason for preferring וְאֶטָּהֵר,  the second version, and for the preponderance of Siddurim with that vowelization, is that the two adjacent verbs sound better and are easier to pronounce when both start with the same vowel, the segol. Grammatically, וְאִטָּהֵר  and  וְאֶטָּהֵר  are equivalent and may be interchanged without changing the meaning; there is no alternate vowelization of  וְאֶתְקַדֵּשׁ.

Answer (score 3):

Could be it's a difference of whether the word is considered to be active/reflexive ("I will purify [myself]") or passive ("I will be purified"). If the former, then it takes a segol, as with words like אֶנָּחֵם (Isaiah 1:24); if the latter, chirik, like אִקָּרֶה (Num. 23:15) or וְאִנָּעֵר (Judg. 16:20).

Comment: That's what the two words mean. But what's the historical/ideological/axiological significance of both's appearing in different siddurim?

Comment: Just to second what @DoubleAA has said: While this is a wonderful explanation of the difference between the two it makes absolutely no mention of any of my questions.

Comment: @yydl: what I was getting at is: (a) yes, there is some source for this difference - it's a matter of grammar; (b) no, it doesn't seem to be a printer's error. Who decided on one form vs. another - that I don't know.

Comment: @Alex a) By "source for difference" I meant an actual Machlokes. b) And how do you know it was not a printer's error? That seems to be a pretty substantial guess (assuming of course that you have no source to back it up)

Comment: First of all, Alex, I don't think there is a difference between "I will purify myself" and "I will be purified" with the same word. I.e. the "myself" was added by you and no version of ואטהר means "and I will purify myself" rather it is either "I will purify" or "I will be purified." I believe that וַאַטַהֵר is "I will purify" and "I will be purified" is וָאֱטָּהֵר. There is also "I will become pure" which is וָאֶטהָר.

Comment: It is possible that the two last (וָאֶטהָר and וָאֶטָהֵר) are the same and the latter (וָאֶטהָר) is only used at the end of a verse or segment. I think that the difference between the two posed in yydl's question have no different interpretation, rather they are just different in pronunciation such as yisgadel and yisgadal. The proofs brought by Alex will not be found in any other way. I.e. You will not find *ikareh* with a segol and neither will you find *ina'er* with a segol. Also, you should not (in tanach there isn't) find *enachem* with a chirik.

Comment: Basically, there is no difference in meaning between the two rather it is based upon the structure of the rest of the word.

Answer (score 3):

To answer yydl's question, as I commented on a previous answer, I believe that the only difference is in the structure of the word and that the two choices have no differences in meaning. As to the answer of which one to say, I have no idea which way is the "right way" but there are many things that can be checked to see if there is consistency in the siddurim being used. First, check all the proofs that Alex used according to the same publisher. Second, you can check the verse in Psalms 51:9.

As a side note, it seems that there is no ת in the ואטהר because it is an irregular verb. Really it should be ואתטהר like ואתקדש because it is a מתפעל. However, interestingly enough, I found a piece from שבט שמעון on page .טו in the version that I found (פרשת בראשית) in which he writes the word ואתטהר when talking about the groom telling the bride that he will become purified through her.

Comment: It's a shame I have to vote this down, because the last paragraph is interesting. However, the first paragraph is critical of another answer and belongs as a comment on that answer, and the second paragraph is a non-answer. Try re-working this to make it more relevant to the question being asked.

Comment: Sorry. Guess I have to understand this site a little better before posting.

Comment: @zukebutt Don't worry about it. Just [edit](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/16048/edit) your answer and try again.

Comment: Nice. Undownvoted. Internally debating whether to upvote or not.

Comment: I don't think Psalms 51:9 is quite the same as there is a shva under the tes (as opposed to in Sefira where there's a kamatz)

Comment: In hitpael forms of verbs starting with Tet ט  and Daled ד, that first consonant absorbs the Tav ת and is doubled with a dagesh.    Thus אטהר not אתטהר.